# Advanced examples of categories

Tags: category-theory, big-list

I'm looking for some example of categories which requires some effort to prove that it is a category (For example it is straightforward  to prove that $\mathbf{Set}$ is a category, I don't want that sort of example).

Comment: In many real life examples, one constructs a candidate for a category and the difficulty is in showing that there is a *set* of morphisms between each pair of objects. This happens when one constructs localizations (the stable category in topology, the derived category in representation theory, etc) It does not make sense to spell out here the constructions, though.

Comment: A simpler example is the Picard category of a commutative ring A, which is the category with one object, whose endomorphisms are the isomorphism classes of invertible R-modules and where composition is given by the tensor product: for this to be a category, you need to show that the class of isomorphism classes if invertible modules is a set.

Comment: The category of [pure Chow motives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motive_(algebraic_geometry)#Third_step:_category_of_pure_Chow_motives.2C_Chow.28k.29) is a good start.

Comment: @Mariano: this seems like a strange use of "Picard category." I'd use this term to refer to the symmetric monoidal category whose objects are invertible $R$-modules, where the monoidal structure is tensor product, and whose morphisms are morphisms or isomorphisms (depending on taste) of $R$-modules. This thing happens to be essentially small but there's no real impediment to studying it if it isn't.

Comment: @qiaochu, well, it is the Picard group of the ring viewed as a category.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For various flavors of [cobordism categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobordism) it can be difficult to prove that composition is well-defined. A typical example is Segal's conformal cobordism category used in conformal field theory, where, loosely speaking,

- the objects are finite disjoint unions of circles, and
- the morphisms between unions of circles are (isomorphism classes of) Riemann surfaces having those circles as boundary.

Composition is given by gluing together Riemann surfaces along common boundaries; it's clear that this can be done topologically, but there's some difficulty in showing that one can compatibly glue smooth and holomorphic structures along the boundaries too. The proof that this is possible is nontrivial; see [conformal welding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_welding) for details.

(Also, as described here, this category doesn't have identity morphisms; those need to be added in by hand.)